# memory barrier usage with CAS operations

Tags: c++11, atomic, memory-barriers

In the code snippet from CPP reference, the memory barriers `std::memory_order_release` and                               `std::memory_order_relaxed` are used for the success and failure cases respectively. When is it OK to use `std::memory_order_release` for both or `std::memory_order_relaxed` for both?

```cpp
template<class T>
struct node
{
    T data;
    node* next;
    node(const T& data) : data(data), next(nullptr) {}
};
 
template<class T>
class stack
{
    std::atomic<node<T>*> head;
 public:
    void push(const T& data)
    {
        node<T>* new_node = new node<T>(data);
 
        // put the current value of head into new_node->next
        new_node->next = head.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
 
        // now make new_node the new head, but if the head
        // is no longer what's stored in new_node->next
        // (some other thread must have inserted a node just now)
        // then put that new head into new_node->next and try again
        while(!std::atomic_compare_exchange_weak_explicit(
                                &head,
                                &new_node->next,
                                new_node,
                                std::memory_order_release,
                                std::memory_order_relaxed))
                ; // the body of the loop is empty
// note: the above loop is not thread-safe in at least
// GCC prior to 4.8.3 (bug 60272), clang prior to 2014-05-05 (bug 18899)
// MSVC prior to 2014-03-17 (bug 819819). See member function version for workaround
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `relaxed` for both would not be safe.  If the `compare_exchange` succeeds, then `head` is updated with the value of `new_node`, and other threads reading `head` will get that pointer.  However, without release ordering, the value written to `new_node->next` (now `head->next`) may not be globally visible yet, so if the other thread tries to read `head->next` it may see garbage, or misbehave in other ways.

Formally, the write to `new_node->next` needs to *happen before* any other thread tries to read it, which can only be ensured by having release ordering on the store that signals other threads that the value is ready.  (Likewise, the thread that reads `head` needs to use acquire ordering.)  With relaxed ordering on the success store, the happens-before relationship is not there, so the code has a data race and its behavior is undefined.

Using `release` for both would not make sense, because release ordering only makes sense for stores, and in the failure case, no store is performed.  In fact, for this reason, passing `std::memory_order_release` for the failure ordering is actually illegal; this is stated on the [page where you got the sample code from](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/compare_exchange).  Using `acquire` or `seq_cst` would be safe (stronger ordering is always safe) but unnecessary, and might cause a needless performance hit.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Can you please elaborate on what the memory ordering actually does with failure cases ? As you point out there are no writes. Does it then correspond to the read (in which case shouldn't it be an acquire read vs. relaxed?) ?

Comment: @user3882729: Correct, the ordering for the failure case applies to the read.  It does not need to be acquire here, because the value read by the the compare-exchange is not used as a signal that other data is ready.  There is no code after the compare-exchange that needs to happen-after anything in particular, neither in the failure nor the success case.

Comment: W.r.t. ```without release ordering, the value written to new_node->next```, this presumably also includes the full content of ```new_node``` incl. data, assuming the write to data can be reordered around ```new_node->next```?

Comment: @user3882729: Yes, it applies to all writes that precede the compare-exchange.  So an incorrect value for `new_node->next` is not the only thing that can go wrong.  As I mentioned, the code formally has undefined behavior, so literally *anything* could go wrong.